# Extracting custom field values from Netsuite <Record>SearchRow objects

Tags: c#, ssis, netsuite

I'm trying to build a C# script that will retrieve a saved Netsuite search and allow me, within SSIS 2008 Script Component, to get those values into a RDBMS.  I am having a devil of a time finding examples of the syntax to get the value of the custom fields.  The Transaction rows I'm dealing with are composed almost entirely of custom fields.

Is it this easy or am I trying to do this too simply?

```
// sr is a Netsuite Search Result defined earlier

while (sr.totalRecords > (sr.pageSize * sr.pageIndex))
{
// output to File
// use StreamWriter to create output file from Connection above

Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", DateTime.Now.ToString() + "Begin loop through records ...", "", 0, ref bul);
foreach (TransactionSearchRow row in sr.searchRowList)
{
    // Now what?
    row.
}
Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", DateTime.Now.ToString() + "... End loop through records", "", 0, ref bul);

sr = service.searchMore(sr.pageIndex + 1);
}  // ** end while (sr.totalRecords > (sr.pageSize * sr.pageIndex))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here.

https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/SchemaBrowser/indexv2013_1_0.html

What sort of search are you doing? TransactionSearch is defined in the common.xsd.

You should have an object inside of each search row called customFieldList. Within customFieldList is an array of all custom field objects, which describe each custom field and provide the custom field contents.